# Matrix ranks and minors

Tags: matrix-rank

Let $A$ be a $n \times n$.

Let $P$ be a $A$ minor $(n-1) \times (n-1)$ with det $\neq 0$.

Let $Q$ be a $P$ minor $(n-2) \times (n-2)$ with det $\neq 0$.

Assume there are more than one $Q$ minor in $A$.

If I find that all determinants $(n-1) \times (n-1)$ "extended" from a particular Q are equal to zero can I conclude that the same will happen for every other Q, i.e. rank of $A$ will be $R = n-2$? Or should I check for every other "extended" determinants $(n-1) \times (n-1)$ from all other particular $Q$?

Comment: Try reformatting your question in mathjax.

Comment: Try to be explicit : it is very difficult to understand 1) Your notations 2) What you ask. Assuming $A$ a square matrix $n \times n$, what do you mean by $A_{minor}$ (any minor of $A$, with dimension $(n-1) \times (n-1)$ ?) and $A_{minor-minor}$: is it a minor of a minor ?

Comment: @JeanMari, Yes to all your questions.

Comment: Knowing that, I have taken the liberty to reformulate your query. I recognize that I have a little salvaged your (somewhat obscure !) initial text ; feel free to modify it again.

Comment: @JeanMarie, ty.